# Edit TextView Items in recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my project I have a recyclerView that populated with bunch of textView items. I want to implement a feature that is:
on long click, textView turns to a editable area that user edit textView to change its value.
how can I implement this feature in viewHolder class?
thanks in advance

Comment: Use an EditText. You can customize the look and feel of the EditText. You could also overlap an EditText and TextView and switch their visibility's when needed.

Comment: Thank you. helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use [View Switcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html). The two children of the ViewSwitcher can be a TextView and an EditText. You can easily switch between the two. You can even customize the transition animation.